# Unhandled activation error while login using visual studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I tried to add `Components` into `Xamarin project` using `visual studio 2015`

I got login screen and after login getting this error -

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

Why ? any clue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read here in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget?tabs=vswin), Xamarin Components is no longer supported and discontinued.

> The Component Store has been discontinued as of May 15, 2018 (this
>   closure was originally announced in November 2017).
>
> Xamarin Components are no longer supported in Visual Studio, and
>   should be replaced by NuGet packages. Follow the instructions below to
>   manually remove component references from your projects.

Comment: ohh is it , they how can i able to use google vision api , any specific uget works for google vision api ?

Comment: @Neo Seems to me this one is it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/ since this is probably the one you looking for: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Vision.v1/ but is a legacy one and explicitly says to use the first one I linked

Comment: oh thanks but i do not find any xamarin code for image reading on github